# add product image via rest api

Tags: magento-1.9, product, catalog

i had done code to add image via webservice api , my code works fine , i just wan to set it as thubmbnail , default and base image how can i do it below is snippet of my code.

error "Image does not exist."

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$app = Mage::app();
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));



//create a new product
try {           

  $serverurl = 'http://******/apis/error2.png';
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
  $stockData = $product->getStockData();
        $stockData['qty'] = 10;
        $stockData['is_in_stock'] = 1;
        $stockData['manage_stock'] = 1;
        $stockData['use_config_manage_stock'] = 0;


    $product->setStoreId('default')
    ->setTypeId('simple')   
    ->setAttributeSetId(4)
    ->setName('4You banner5')
    ->setDescription("This widget will give you years of trouble-free widgeting.")
    ->setShortDescription("High-end widget.")
    ->setSku('4you5')
    ->setWeight(1.0)
    ->setStatus(1)
    ->setVisibility(4)
    ->setPrice(15.49)
    ->addImageToMediaGallery($serverurl,array('thumbnail','small_image','image'),true,false)
    ->setTaxClassId(0)
    ->setStockData($stockData)
    ->setCategoryIds('3')
    ->setHasOptions(1)
    ->setProductOptions(array($options))
    ->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true)
    ->save();   

  echo 'OK Product ID: '.$product->getId();

      $cache = Mage::getSingleton('core/cache');
      $cache->flush();
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153891/magento-how-to-programatically-set-the-base-image-to-the-first-image-in-the-lis